Is this an accurate interpretation of the elasticity magus arcana?
Now I admit this is kind of flimsy but I wanted to double check just to be sure.

Kapenia Dancer Arcana: A kapenia dancer gains access to the following magus arcana. He cannot select any arcana more than once.
Elasticity (Su): As a free action, the kapenia dancer can spend 1 point from his arcane pool in order to grant a bladed scarf he’s wielding reach until the end of his turn. A kapenia dancer can use this arcana in tandem with other magus arcana.

Note how it says free action meaning it can be activated when it isn't your turn.
So here's how I'm looking at it you do your thing as a magus, buff, reposition all that and end your turn, then once someone else starts their turn or tries to run past you, you activate elasticity giving you reach that keeps going until the end of your next turn.
Given what I know I feel this is an accurate interpretation, what do you think?


Note how it says free action meaning it can be activated when it isn't your turn.

Nope; free actions (usually) have to be on your turn. Only speaking gets a special exception allowing you to perform that free action even when it isn’t your turn. Other free actions are still required to be during your turn.
So no, you can only use elasticity during your turn, and its benefits do not extend past the end of that same turn. You cannot use it to gain reach on attacks of opportunity during other creatures’ turns.

Welp, Worth asking.
